# Does recurly count transaction for amount $0?

Tags: recurly

I have some questions regrading Recurly integration.

1. As mentions recurly charges per transaction. If any transaction is done for $0.00 amount(In case of Free plan), would Recurly count this as a transaction & deduct the transaction charges ?
2. Is their any invoice limit & charges ?
3. Do you store credit card information on your end or it is stored on the side of payment gatways ?

Answer (score 3):

1. A $0 invoice against a credit card will not result in a transaction being released to a payment gateway and thus you would not be charged in this case. However, Recurly does authorize cards when initially captured (using a zero dollar authorization) and the per-transaction cost applies. This happens at the beginning of a free trial period.
2. There is no limit to the number of invoices you can generate. Manual invoices (invoices paid with anything other than a credit card or PayPal account) cost $1/invoice.
3. Recurly stores credit card information in its own secure credit card vault. Recurly is a PCI Level 1 Provider.